# Modify value of string in for loop

Tags: java, string

It may sound so silly to ask but still I want to know      what will happen if i assign value of string within for loop. Let's say

```
 String name = " darsha" ;

 for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ )
{
     name = darsha ; 
}
```

What will happen internally?  Will there be only one name instance in string pool or 10

Comment: Only 1! Also `name = darsha ; ` is wrong, It should be `name = " darsha" ;`

Comment: it will throw compilation error. because darsha is not defined. It will treat darsha as a variable.

Comment: As you said, `it is silly`.

Comment: If it should be `" darsha"`, instead of just `darsha` it would have one String in the pool. Ssince this pool is build at compile time it notices that this literal exists twice and makes this literal use the same reference from the pool at runtime.

Comment: Also the loop is missing an `int` before `i`

Answer (score 1):

This will unnecessary utilize memory as well cpu of your machine.
As output going to ramain the same that name="darsha"
So unneccesary wasting of memory,cpu utilization 7 wastage of java heap nothing else.
     String name = " darsha" ;

```
 for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ )
{
     name = "darsha" ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there will only be ONE `name` instance. :)

and there is a mistake in your internal `name` as well. It should be corrected with inverted commas as the *darsha* is a `string` value. `name = " darsha" ;`

Answer (score 0):

You must add int before "i" in the loop,and it should be " darsha", instead of just darsha,if you modify like that the last result is name = " darsha"